# Decoding hash lookups

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

I have this problem that sounds like a classic computer science trick - I am sure there is an easy solution but I just don't know what the problem / solution is called so have been unable to Google it. If someone could just point me in the right direction as to terminology, that would really help, but the closest thing I could find to this was 'hash table'.
Here's the problem:

Imagine that you have every day of the week listed, Sun through to Sat, with a checkbox next to each day.

Something can happen, eg. email being sent, it doesn't matter. It can happen on any combination of those days, such as, every Saturday and Sunday, or every Monday Thursday and Friday.

Sun = 2, Mon = 4, Tue = 8, Wed = 16, Thur = 32, Fri = 64, Sat = 128

..so if it happens every Monday and Tuesday, the value stored in the database is 4 + 8 = 12. If it happens every Friday (64) and Saturday (128), the value is 192 etc..

How on earth do you make the code that can take the number and work out which days of the week are selected?

Again, if someone were to reply 'this is an example of xxx' that would really help me Google my way out of this problem, then I would share my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, this is what you are looking for:

```
while a > 0:
  mod = a % 2
  if mod != 0:
    print(str(counter) + " day selected")
    a -= 1
  a = a/2
  counter += 1
```

Your number (a in example) is summ of 2^n, like 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^6. You can just divide your number by 2 until you meet an odd number. It will be like 2^3(1 + 2^2 + 2^3). Then you shold substract 1, and repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

I don' think it is related to hash tables, but the number code in the question itself should provide hint! Try to search something along the line of `binary` in google.

```
'sun' ->2 ->10 (binary-like)
'mon' ->4  ->100(binary-like)
....
```

Given that the days are all unique (e.g. you do not have two events on mondays), you can evetually get an 8-digit binary code from 00000000 to 11111111. Here, '1' on index i indicates an event on day (7-i).

Below is some codes (but not the only) that work:

```
def tobit(d):
    return "{0:b}".format(d)
Dict1={2:'sun',4:'mon',8:'tue',16:'wed',32:'thu',64:'fri',128:'sun'}
def todays(d):
    days=tobit(d)
    for i,item in enumerate(days):
        if item=='1':
            print(Dict1[2**(len(days)-i-1)])
```

say `todays(48)` will return wed and thu

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for **bitwise operators**. Each of these numbers, represented in binary, consists of a single 1 bit with many trailing zeros. You can use the bitwise AND operator to see if one of those bits is set:

```
if ((number & Monday) != 0) {
    // Monday is included
}
```

You can set one of the bits to true using the bitwise OR operator:

```
number |= Monday;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers! They were all helpful and gave me a sense of how to solve the problem. I code in php and javascript but have no formal education in maths or computing, this is my 'cowboy' solution to the problem:

Example: Mon (4) + Wed (16) + Thu (32) = 52

52 in binary is 110100. I treat the binary number as a string now, and if it is less than 8 characters long then I pad it out with 0's at the front, ie. 00110100. Then I chop off the last '0', 0011010. Then I reverse the string, 0101100, and there you have it - 7 zeros and ones, that you can loop through and match with an array of the days of the week:

0 1(mon) 0 1(wed) 1(thu) 0 0

Comment: I've just learned a bit more about bitwise operators since my cowboy approach above, and now the comments below make a lot more sense to me - this video helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mesu75PTDC8